# JavaScript - Function Issue

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'm new using JavaScript and I'm trying to accomplish the follow exercise:

I have an array named `bill` with 3 elements `[124, 48, 268]`

I want to call a function which calculates the tip depending on bill amount, less than $50 (percentage = 0.2), bill amount between $50 and $ 200 (percentage = 0.15) and bill amount over $ 200 (percentage = 0.1)

I have used the following code:

```js
    var bill = [124, 48, 268];

    var percCalculation = function(amount) {
        var percentage;
        switch(amount) {
            case (amount < 50):
                percentage = .2;
            case (amount >= 50 && amount < 200):
                percentage = .15;
            case (amount > 200):
                percentage = .1;
        }
        return percentage * amount
    }

    var tipAmount = [percCalculation(bill[0]),
    percCalculation(bill[1]),
    percCalculation(bill[2])];

    console.log(tipAmount);
```

However, I get the following results: `(3) [NaN, NaN, NaN]`

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: After finding the problem, I suggest you learn about the `map()` function.

Comment: learn how to use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) - you're doing it very wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `switch` cases "fall-through", as in keep executing until hitting a `break`, `return` or the end of the `switch`, so:

```js
var percCalculation = function(amount) {
var percentage;
switch(amount) {
    case (amount < 50):
        percentage = .2;
        break;
    case (amount >= 50 && amount < 200):
        percentage = .15;
        break;
    case (amount > 200):
        percentage = .1;
        break;
}
return percentage * amount
}

var bill = [124, 48, 268];
var tipAmount = [percCalculation(bill[0]),
percCalculation(bill[1]),
percCalculation(bill[2])];

console.log(tipAmount);
```

While that fixes the fall-through problem, it exposes another more serious one
and that is the `case` values are evaluated through matching, as in `amount`
must match one of the *fully evaluted* versions of those `case` expressions,
so this looks like:

```
switch(amount) {
  case true:
     // ...
  case false:
     // ...
  case false:
     // ...
}
```

So it must be converted to `if` statements:

```js
var percCalculation = function(amount) {
var percentage;
if (amount < 50)
    percentage = .2;
if (amount >= 50 && amount < 200)
    percentage = .15;
if (amount > 200)
    percentage = .1;

return percentage * amount;
}

var bill = [124, 48, 268];
var tipAmount = [percCalculation(bill[0]),
percCalculation(bill[1]),
percCalculation(bill[2])];

console.log(tipAmount);
```

Note you have an error in your logic, if `amount` is `200` it will not match
anything and crash out using an `undefined` value in multiplication. I prefer
to use more data-driven definitions, like this:

```
percentageForAmount = [
  [ 200, 0.1 ],
  [ 50, 0.15 ],
  [ 0, 0.2 ]
];
```

Where you can look up values in that easily:

```
let rate = percentageForAmount.find((min, perc) => amount > min);

let percentage = rate[1];
```

It's also worth noting that it's generally better to define functions as functions, not as `var` variables. There's no reason to redefine this each time you run it as nothing changes.

In other words:

```
function percCalculation(amount) {
  // ...
}
```

Where you can call that as many times as you want with no additional overhead.

Comment: @JaromandaX I had a working version that got a ninja edit. Working on it

Comment: In my case, the function is not recognizing the numbers on the array as a number and I dont know why

Comment: @tadman My bad. I'm attempting to edit your code into a snippet while it appears that you are still working on your answer.

Comment: it's just `switch(true)` ... :p

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos What do you mean "not recognizing the numbers on the array as a number"? What do you see when you debug the code that leads to this conclusion?

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos the numbers are recognised as such, you just used switch wrong

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Appreciate the snippet treatment, but it was just bad timing.

Comment: your are right @Jaromanda X; after I changed to tru on switch, it worked

Comment: @tadman I was mostly doing it for myself because I suspected that just adding `break` didn't actually fix the problem. But I wanted to run your code before saying anything.

Comment: I removed the colons but now get "Illegal return statement" in your example with `if` statements.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's a multi-layered problem, there's several issues with the original code, and I've tried to untangle them here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah, got those in the first edit, missed in the second. Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

your switch statement for the first amount, 124 would look like

```
var percentage = undefined; // implied value of undeifned
switch(124) {
  case false: ......
  case true: ....
  case false: ....
}
return 124 * undefined; // this is Nan
```

Since no cases match 124, percentage never gets a value, and you get NaN as a result

So, you want to `switch(true)` as only one case will ever be true

You also want to `break` at the end of each case so the execution doesn't "fall through" to the next case

A little bonus, your function can be used as a callback to Array#map method - see bottom of snippet

```js
var percCalculation = function(amount) {
    var percentage;
    switch(true) {
        case (amount < 50):
            percentage = .2;
            break;
        case (amount >= 50 && amount < 200):
            percentage = .15;
            break;
        case (amount > 200):
            percentage = .1;
            break;
    }
    return (percentage * amount).toFixed(2) // returns a nice dollar and cents
}

var bill = [124, 48, 268];
var tipAmount = [percCalculation(bill[0]),
percCalculation(bill[1]),
percCalculation(bill[2])];

console.log(tipAmount);

// bonus ... use map to make your code "DRY"
var tip2 = bill.map(percCalculation);
console.log(tip2);
```

Please note: your logic would mean that if the amount is exactly 200, you will get a NaN result ... you need to either check <= 200 in second case or >= 200 in third case (as you've done for the 50 cutoff)

a brief note about the above usage of switch ... many languages have `switch` but won't allow multiple `case` with the same value - javascript does (not sure which other languages allow it) so, just be careful if using another language